# Python script to check active website trackers

Tags: javascript, python, html, get, command-line-interface

Quick questions, and a simple one at that but having trouble finding anything via google, etc.

I want to write a python script, that can visit a list of given URL's and check that URL for any redirects to see which trackers are active on the site.

Currently it works, but because it runs in command line- none of the javascript is executed and JS contains the majority of trackers (google analytics etc).

Any advice as to point me in the right direction to get the javascript to execute from command line and store those GET requests in memory ?

(UNIX)

Comment: Have you  looked into `headless browsers` ?

Comment: [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) for example

Comment: @nightgaunt thanks for pointing me in right direction. I will have a look and update this post accordingly!